# Mongodb bulk.insert issues with db and concurrent response from db

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mern

I've developed a multi user app where I can login and upload a csv file. The data is extracted from the csv file into objects (about 10000) and then the data/object(s) is/are inserted into mongodb. I've tried differnt mongodb insert option. The fastest is the bulk.insert option. It inserts about 200 objects per second. Following is my bulk.insert code:

```
        const bulk = db.collection('mycollection').initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
        bulk.insert(csvData);
        bulk.execute();
```

But the issue with this bulk insert is that while data is inserted to mongodb I cannot view other pages (the pages that read data from the same db). Also, other users cannot login to the website. The website has just one db with different collections.

I tried normal insert option also. Following is the code:

```
await db.collection("mycollection").insert(csvData);
```

With this option, other users can login, I can view other pages. But, the insert speed is some 9 times slower (About 24 inserts per second).

With bulk operation, it seems, while mongodb is busy with one query, it does not respond to other queries. Please suggest me a way to increase insert speed and at the same time make the db accessible to others.

Comment: Have you found the bottleneck?  You will probably need to look at things like cache size, disk/cpu/memory utilization, etc.

Comment: Actually I have no idea how I can fix the issue. At the moment, probably I need to sacrifice insert speed just to avoid login and access issues for the other users. That means, normal insert option is the way to go.